# Unity 2D, get joystick direction

Tags: unity-game-engine

im making a mobile game, the player have a grappling hook and can fly with it (just like spider man), i use some script so the grappling hook is work base on mouse position, but the problem is i want to convert it to mobile game, i can just use leave it as is since click on touch is same as mouse click, but i want to use joystick to get direction. i want make it  the same as the fanny mechanism in a mobile legend game, (if you know the game)

i use this script for targeting 
on pc (which is fine)

```
 if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0))
        {
            Vector2 worldPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            rope.setTarget(worldPos); // hook script will get this value
        }
```

i try use this for mobile (the problem):

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0))
        {
            float inputX = joystick.Horizontal;
            float inputY = joystick.Vertical;
            Vector2 dir = new Vector2(inputX, inputY);
            rope.setTarget(dir); // hook script will get this value
        }
```

Comment: Instead of `Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0)`, try using `Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture a joystick, it can be achieved through the Input Manager [`GetAxis`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetAxis.html) function, which can read a Joystick, Mouse or Keyboard arrows/asdw, according to how you configure it.

In code, you would use:

```cs
float inputX = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
float inputY = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
```

If you don't want to have the mouse to look, just configure it in `Edit > Project Settings > Input > Axes`. There are two "Horizontal" and two "Vertical" configurations. Let exist only that with Joystick configuration and delete the other. Below, it is the image of the axis configured for joysticks:

[image]

For more information, check https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-InputManager.html. I hope that helps you to get started!

**EDIT: Virtual/screen joysticks on mobile**

In the case you are talking about virtual/screen joysticks, you must control it manually, in the hard way. To develop this kind of joystick, you will use the Input Manager to get the mouse/touch position during press (`Input.GetMouseButtonDown(int)`), release (`Input.GetMouseButtonUp(int)`) and drag (`Input.GetMouseButton(int)`). Then you control how much the mouse has moved since the user began to press it and clamp the position to not overflow the joystick area.

As you have stated in comments, you have downloaded an asset from Asset Store. The way the assets work are unique and it is up to their developers to tell how you should use them. Seek for documentation, tutorials and examples given by the developer to see how the asset is intended to be used.

Comment: ok so i use premade joystick that i downloaded from assets store, i dont know how to use it using axis, i try refrence that joystick and use joystick.GetAxis but it doesnt work. so how can i get the joystick axis?

Comment: Oh, you are talking about a virtual/screen joystick. It was not clever in the question, because there are real joysticks/gamepads for mobile. In this case, Input Manager will not help at all. I will update my answer, but I fear "how to use this asset" is somewhat off-topic in Stack Overflow, if you are not having a specific problem for following the asset documentation.

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention, yeah it is a virtual juystick